# Newly created SPFx web part using react framework gives error with SharePoint online workbench while testing

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, workbench

I have just created one SPFx web part with react framework. I tried testing through SharePoint online workbench (https://demo.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx).

I am getting an error. Chrome browser developer tool shows below error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://localhost:4321/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js
https://localhost:4321/node_modules/react/dist/react.js
```

Based on above mentioned error, I noticed the "node_modules/react/" does not contains "dist" folder at all.

Comment: Is it running properly on local workbench? make sure `gulp serve` is running properly and try hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) on SharePoint workbench once after gulp serve is running. which version of SPFx generator you are using?

Comment: Gulp serve is in running state. I am using @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0

Comment: Did you try running this web part in local workbench?

Comment: Yes Ganesh,I tried running the webpart in workbench. Actually the webpart is retriving one list data and displaying those over the form.Within the local workbench it does not show up those data as the sharepoint site it refers to provides forbidden error.this is fine.

But when I am testing with SP Online site workbench where the actual list is present, there it throws mentioned two JS not found. I can see the data is getting retrieved through chrome browser console but not getting rendered due to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, I could reproduce this issue on my end. It seems to be a bug that on SharePoint online workbench it tries to request node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js instead of the react library

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This file type unsupported by office version

Comment: If so, how do I be able to test my react spfx webpart with sharepoint online workbench?Please can you guide?